# Shadows in Workbench

Tags: shadows, workbench-render-engine

So Blender Devs were working on a cool feature of Workbench engine, that is rendering sharp shadows. They are rendered in the way that SketchUp viewport or ArchiCAD and some other CAD-like programs use, which is OpenGL shading (correct me if I'm wrong). Shadows are cast precisely, and they use vector methods to display terminators.
Sneak peek was posted here:
https://www.blendernation.com/2018/05/03/blender-2-8-code-quest-new-shadows-in-the-workbench-engine/#comment-913693

Anybody knows if this feature is available and how to turn on Workbench shadows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature can be enabled both for the viewport and a final render with the workbench engine.

When the render engine is set to *Workbench* the option can be found in *Render Properties > Options > Shadow*.

[image: Workbench Shadow]

When the *Viewport Shading* is set to *Solid*, the same option is available for the viewport.

[image: Viewport Shading]

Comment: Cool! Thank you very, very much :D

Comment: Doing this gives me self shadows but doesn't cast shadows. You guys get cast?

Comment: @wilks Yes, for instance adding a plane as floor will have shadows cast on it from objects located above.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Right, worked it out, looks like it stopped working in 2.91alpha, well at least my version from 3 weeks ago =D It works fine in 2.90, cheers!

Comment: @wilks You're welcome! Should be fixed since since 28th of August (see [T80160](https://developer.blender.org/T80160)).

Comment: @RobertGützkow yep, just re-downloaded and it works, cool! Funnily enough I'd downloaded on the 28th what must have been the previous day's build!